# How do you insert a embedded gif into an Outlook Email Signature? I want to insert a gif into my email signature that links to a website

Tags: email, outlook, hyperlink, gif, electronic-signature

I am trying to insert a gif into my outlook signature where the gif when clicked on, takes you to a  website.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

I have the gif saved in my files, I have tried inserting it into my email signature but unable to connect the link to it.